# N-Dimensional summation without data copy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Right now I have a 2 dimensional function that works as intended:

```
def wavestep2d(U,dx, dz, dt):
    U = (dt/dx)**2 * fourth_order(U, dx, axis=0) +
        (dt/dz)**2 * fourth_order(U, dz, axis=1)   
    return U
```

Of course I could extend to 3d just adding a line as:

```
def wavestep3d(U,dv, dt):
    """dv here is a N sized array with dx_1, dx_2, ..., dx_N"""
    U = (dt/dv[0])**2 * fourth_order(U, dv[0], axis=0) +
        (dt/dv[1])**2 * fourth_order(U, dv[1], axis=1) +
        (dt/dv[2])**2 * fourth_order(U, dv[2], axis=2)   
    return U
```

And could do the same for 4d (one more line), 5d (2 more lines) and goes on and on. but Infinity isn't my friend. Therefore I want to extend that for the N dimensional case, something like this:

```
def wavestepNd(U, dv, dt):
    """dv here is a N sized array with dx_1, dx_2, ..., dx_N"""
    for i in range(len(U.shape)):
        U += (dt/dv[i])**2 * fourth_order(U, dv[i], axis=i)   
    return U
```

The issue here is that U is being changed in each iteration in for loop instead using the same U.

Of course I could do something like:

```
def wavestepNd_with_copy(U, dv, dt):
    """dv here is a N sized array with dx_1, dx_2, ..., dx_N"""
    U_temp = np.zeros_like(U)
    for i in range(len(U.shape)):
        U_temp += (dt/dv[i])**2 * fourth_order(U, dv[i], axis=i)  
    return U_temp
```

But this case incur in doubling the memory and U can get very large.

Is there an good approach for this?

### EDIT 1:

Adding the referenced functions as requested.

```
def fourth_order_term(U, axis=-1):
    U = U.swapaxes(0, axis)
    fm2 = U[ :-4]
    fm1 = U[1:-3]
    fc0 = U[2:-2]
    fp1 = U[3:-1]
    fp2 = U[4:  ]
    return (fm2 - 16*(fm1+fp1) + 30*fc0 + fp2).swapaxes(0, axis)

def fourth_order(U, dv, axis=-1):
    mul = 1/(12 * dv[axis]**2)
    return mul * fourth_order_term(U, axis=axis)
```

Comment: Are you performing differentiation? There are functions to do that, iirc.

Comment: Will you please write the definition of `fourth_order()`? Thank you.

Comment: What's the big deal?  Do you want to keep the original `U` as well as the result of the `waves` function?  `wavestep2d` does that.  The `U` that is returned is not the same array object that was passed in.

Comment: @coldspeed Yes. Writing differentiation, I know it did exist. But they are limited in precision order.

Comment: @hpaulj wavestep2d does that, I know. But I want to extend to Ndimensional  wavefields. I don't want to write a function to every number of dmentions, of course I could write one for 3d just adding a line, for 4d two lines and goes on. I could even write a wrapper function to call the "correct one".  but IMHO isn't elegant and I'm looking for a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: You don't want to start the iterative version with a U copy.  You want a zeros like U

Comment: @hpaulj that is true. That was a mistake. But I don't want any memory allocation doubling at all.

Comment: Are you measuring memory allocation? Guessing is unreliable, even if you know numpy well.

Comment: Can you give a numerical example?

Comment: @hpaulj no, no need for measuring. That memory usage grows cubically, a 1000 sided (not that big), will take 32 GB on memory, and I do not need to spend the cost of memory copy for 32GB for every iteration of this code (it will run sometimes more than 100.000 times)

Comment: Yes you can calculate the size of `U`.  But how temporary arrays of that size are being created during the calculation?  I'm estimating that `fourth_order_term` makes 4 temporary arrays of that size.  `wavestep2d` makes 2 which it sums to produce the return value.  `3d` sums 3 arrays.  Compared to that the iterative version has `U_temp` and just one temporary RHS array each loop.

Comment: no. because in Numpy, slicing is just a view to the data (aka pointers), but when I copy I do a real memcpy, doubling the memory. All other functions work over the data itself, not on copies.

Comment: `fm1+fp1` is a new array even though the elements are views.  `30*fc0` is also new.  A `view` shares the data buffer of the original, but most math involving a `view` creates a new array with new data.  `U_temp += ...` is the only in-place math in your code.

Comment: @hpaulj good to know about that. therefore I *NEED* to put the slices in a single ine instead assign variable names for readibility.

Comment: That's not going to change things. The variable name is just a reference to the `view` object.  It's used the same way.